# Conditional subtraction of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays which hold the data of my products. Sample below.

`$transfer_in` array

```
  Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [product_qty] => 32
            [product_pcs] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [product_qty] => 353
            [product_pcs] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_qty] => 11
            [product_pcs] => 1
        )
)
```

`$transfer_out` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_qty] => 1
            [product_pcs] => 1
        )
)
```

Now I have to subtract the two arrays with specific `product_id` of the product.
If `product_id` from both arrays are the same/ exist then subtract it.
`$transfer_in['product_qty']`-`$transfer_out['product_qty']` and `$transfer_in['product_pcs']`-`$transfer_out['product_pcs']`

How can I subtract each `product_qty` and `product_pcs` with same `product_id` on both arrays and put them as one array?

Expected output should be:

```
$output = 
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [product_qty] => 32
            [product_pcs] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [product_qty] => 353
            [product_pcs] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_qty] => 10
            [product_pcs] => 0
        )
)
```

Comment: just use two foreach loops, and an if statement, inside the if statement, make the subtraction

Comment: with a loop and some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop it and check if the key is `product_id` and if `transfer_in` and `transfer_out` `product_id`is equal

**Solution**

```
$transfer_in = array
    (
    0 => array
        (
            'product_id' => 2,
            'product_qty' => 32,
            'product_pcs' => 0
        ),
    1 => array
        (
            'product_id' => 3,
            'product_qty' => 353,
            'product_pcs' => 2
        ),
    2 => array
        (
            'product_id' => 5,
            'product_qty' => 11,
            'product_pcs' => 1
        )
);


$transfer_out = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'product_id'=> 5,
            'product_qty' => 1,
            'product_pcs' => 1
        )
);

foreach($transfer_in as $in_key => $in_product){
    foreach($transfer_out as $out_key => $out_product){

        if( $out_key == 'product_id' && $in_product['product_id'] == $out_product['product_id']){
            $transfer_in[$in_key]['product_qty'] = $in_product['product_qty'] - $out_product['product_qty'];
            $transfer_in[$in_key]['product_pcs'] = $in_product['product_pcs'] - $out_product['product_pcs'];
        }
    }
}

//Print Result
foreach($transfer_in as $in_key => $in_product){
    echo $in_key . '<br />';
    foreach($in_product as $out_key => $out_product){
        echo $out_key . ' = ' . $out_product . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0
product_id = 2
product_qty = 32
product_pcs = 0

1
product_id = 3
product_qty = 353
product_pcs = 2

2
product_id = 5
product_qty = 10
product_pcs = 0
```

Comment: It is working now. I have to change some variables. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ..No problem :)